# Java EE, Tomcat, Servlets: Push message to specific client

Tags: java, servlets, push, tomcat7

In my web-app, i need to push specific messages to my clients in real time. Web-sockets would be a good idea, but they don't work in IE, which should be supported as well.

Until recently we have been using StreamHub, but it's license has expired and the project itself seems to be dead. We also considered jWebSockets, but they seem a bit of overkill.

Again, all we need to do is to send messages from the server to **specific** clients as events happen on the server.

Could you recomend a lightweight, free and opensource solution for that?

Answer (score 2):

Here's an opensource [Java implementation of Socket.IO](http://code.google.com/p/socketio-java/). It allows you to use Ajax mulitpart streaming to simulate WebSockets when your client doesn't support them. I've used it on projects in the past. It's horribly out of date with the most recent implementation of the WebSocket protocol, so if you plan on using WebSocket capable browsers in addition to IE, you'll have to update the source code to comply with the [latest protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-17). At one point I was researching a maintained replacement for Java Socket.IO and jWebSockets sounded like the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [Atmosphere WebSocket/Comet library](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere).  I believe it can use long polling when WebSockets aren't supported.